# How to create a deep link similar to firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, ios, mobile, firebase, deep-linking

**How dynamic links work for firebase.** 
I mean how deep link is maintained even when app is downloaded from app store or play store and then opened.

Comment: They are using a private API inside Google Play Services and provide an extra Bundle to the Play Store app.

Comment: I can understand about private api on Google Play but sorry i am not able to understand your point on submitting extra Bundle.

Comment: Google Play Services is using an Intent to start the Play Store app which contains extras parameters grouped in a Bundle